# Weird Java extended ascii error

Tags: java

I'm trying to do a comparison in Java with 2 strings containing a extended ASCII character.

```
boolean result = "éasdfasdf".substring(0,1).equals("é");
```

Can somebody explain why this results false? I think it has something to do with character encoding, but I can't figure out what exactly the problem is here...

Update: ideone.com does successfully run these 2 lines, so the problem is locally in my box. I think I found some more proof of that:

```
System.out.println("éb".charAt(1) == 'b');
```

Does also fails... Can it be the problem of 2 different character encodings?

Comment: Search for String comparison in Java.

Comment: Try `boolean result = "éasdfasdf".substring(0,1).equals("é");`

Comment: `boolean result = "éasdfasdf".codePointAt(0) == 'é';` for simple char-s.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
boolean result = "éasdfasdf".substring(0,1).equals("é")
```

And it will give expected result!

The reason is simple - using '==' you compare objects by reference, not by value. So `equals()` solves this problem

Comment: @VincentTeuben - Nope. It doesnt. It returns `true`

Comment: Yes, sure, equals() doesn't fail:)

Comment: Before you gave a answer, please try it, because there is something fishy going on here.
System.out.println("éasdfasdf".substring(0,1).equals("é"));
Fails on my Windows box

Comment: Don't doubt - I've tried it. It goes ok on my system and, for example, here: http://ideone.com/

Comment: Indeed, ideone gives me true, I copied the exact sources from ideoone and tried it in IntelliJ14, JDK 1.7.0_51, Windows and that gives me a false.

Comment: You say that it behaves different on different systems (doesn't work on Windows). It has never occurred to me. Suspect it happens due to unicode/locale settings. It deserves new question. If you get answer please let me know